# Using standard types

Tags: uml-designer

Is there a way to configure `uml-designer` to understand standard C and C++ library types (like `uint32_t` or `std::string`)? Right now it refuses to let me assign a type to a variable if this type doesn't exist in the model.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to define them. To do so you can provide your own profile in which you define all the Datatypes you need, this will be your types library model. And then you can use this types in any other model by referencing the types from your libray. 
To define the types you juste create a model as you do usually and then to use them in another model you can reference the profile by clicking on `Project Dependencies` in the *Model Explorer* and then on `Add Model`:
[image: Add Model]

A dialog box opens, and then you have to select on your file system the .uml model which definies the types:
[image: Select File]

In my example this file is named types.uml:
[image: Types.uml]

Then you validate and you can see in the *Model Explorer* your profiles un the `Project Dependencies`.

[image: Project Dependencies]

Now you can use the types in your model. For example, I created a class with a property and I want to set the property type to `Date`. Then I clixk on the + utton in the properties view and this open a dialog which by default is on the Model REsource tab. I select the All Resources tab and then I am able to select the Date type.
[image: Use the Type]

In the end I got a property with Date as type:
[image]

Comment: Does this `tipes.uml` file exists somewhere for std library? Otherwise, based on your procedure, I will have to make my own and all all standard types to it manually.

Comment: Yes you have to do it manually. UML designer provides only the UML types. For other types library you have to create your own.